# MDF to CSV Conversion? Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, csv, mdf

Is there a way I can convert my MDF database to a CSV for supported webhost? If so could anyone enlighten me on how?

Comment: 1) an MDF is a database and a CSV would be a single table so you are dead from the get-go. 2) Why not just open the database in SQL server and then export the data to files?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that actually..

Comment: Get a copy of SQL Server and SSMS and then read the documentation. It is a simple operation you should be able to figure out on your own.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Open the MDF file in SQL server as it was intended then run and export a query from each table. You will have one CSV for each table.

I have no clue what you mean by "for supported webhost". Please put more effort into your question if you want someone to spend time answering it.

Comment: supported webhost meaning a webhost that supports CSV my apologies

Comment: You do this in SQL Server Management Studio, not VS. Also "A webhost that supports CSV is a nonsense statement".  Webhosts support website platforms not file formats. Whatever you are trying to do it seriously sounds like you are probably doing it wrong.